# How to save RecyclerView's scroll position using RecyclerView.State?

Tags: android, state, android-recyclerview

I have a question about Android's [RecyclerView.State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.State.html).

I am using a RecyclerView, how could I use and bind it with RecyclerView.State?

My purpose is to **save the RecyclerView's scroll position**.

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645664/3904109

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How do you plan to save last saved position with `RecyclerView.State`?

You can always rely on ol' good save state. Extend `RecyclerView` and override onSaveInstanceState() and `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

```
    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        LayoutManager layoutManager = getLayoutManager();
        if(layoutManager != null && layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager){
            mScrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        SavedState newState = new SavedState(superState);
        newState.mScrollPosition = mScrollPosition;
        return newState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        if(state != null && state instanceof SavedState){
            mScrollPosition = ((SavedState) state).mScrollPosition;
            LayoutManager layoutManager = getLayoutManager();
            if(layoutManager != null){
              int count = layoutManager.getItemCount();
              if(mScrollPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && mScrollPosition < count){
                  layoutManager.scrollToPosition(mScrollPosition);
              }
            }
        }
    }

    static class SavedState extends android.view.View.BaseSavedState {
        public int mScrollPosition;
        SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            mScrollPosition = in.readInt();
        }
        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(mScrollPosition);
        }
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: now I have another question, how , no , what is RecyclerView.State can do?

Comment: does this really work? I have tried this, but I keep getting a runtime exception like this: MyRecyclerView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState

Comment: On the restore instance state we need to pass the superState to its super class (the recytcler view) like this:
super.onRestoreInstanceState(((ScrollPositionSavingRecyclerView.SavedState) state).getSuperState());

Comment: This doesn't work if you extend the RecyclerView, you'll get BadParcelException.

Comment: Do you extend the activity or the adapter?

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski I have a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176812/android-restore-recyclerview-item-positions-after-app-re-opens.  I would appreciate any insights you have on how to solve.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I restored my `Fragment`, my `LinearLayoutManager.childCount` was always `0`.

Comment: @HeathBorders try it now. I currently edited this post. A problem was with .childCount. Use .itemcount instead of it.

Comment: None of this is necessary : if you use something like LinearLayoutManager / GridLayoutManager the "scroll position" is already saved automatically for you. (It's the mAnchorPosition in LinearLayoutManager.SavedState). If you're not seeing that, then something is wrong with how you are reapplying data.

Comment: `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` isn't compiling.

Answer (score 253):

### Update

Starting from `recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02` release `StateRestorationPolicy` has been introduced. It could be a better approach to the given problem.

This topic has been covered on [android developers medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334).

Also, @rubén-viguera shared more details in the answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609823/892500

### Old answer

If you are using LinearLayoutManager, it comes with pre-built save api [linearLayoutManagerInstance.onSaveInstanceState()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and restore api [linearLayoutManagerInstance.onRestoreInstanceState(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#LinearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29)

With that, you can save the returned parcelable to your outState. e.g.,

```
outState.putParcelable("KeyForLayoutManagerState", linearLayoutManagerInstance.onSaveInstanceState());
```

, and restore restore position with the state you saved. e.g,

```
Parcelable state = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("KeyForLayoutManagerState");
linearLayoutManagerInstance.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

To wrap all up, your final code will look something like

```
private static final String BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT = "classname.recycler.layout";

/**
 * This is a method for Fragment. 
 * You can do the same in onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState
 */
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT);
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

**Edit:** You can also use the same apis with the GridLayoutManager, as it is a subclass of LinearLayoutManager. Thanks @wegsehen for the suggestion.

**Edit:** Remember, if you are also loading data in a background thread, you will need to a call to onRestoreInstanceState within your onPostExecute/onLoadFinished method for the position to be restored upon orientation change, e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (movies != null) {
        showMoviePosterDataView();
        mDataAdapter.setMovies(movies);
      mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mSavedRecyclerLayoutState);
        } else {
            showErrorMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer, why is this not accepted? Note that any LayoutManager has that, not only LinearLayoutManager, also GridLayoutManager, and if not its a false implementation.

Comment: linearLayoutManager.onInstanceState() always returns null --> check the source code. Unfortunately not working.

Comment: @Andev, that is true for abstract class LayoutManager. All implementing subclasses (Linear, Grid, Staggered) returns a Parcelable. Here is my reference for LinearLayoutManager, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#214

Comment: Just a warning - I got NPE in certain cases, so do some null checks when using it - otherwise great. Simple.

Comment: Does not work with stackfFromEnd. Duh, can something work as intended on Android some day?

Comment: this should definitely be the accepted answer. Haven't had any problem with that and it saves the exact scroll position and state.

Comment: Doesn't RecyclerView do the state save of its LayoutManager in its own onSaveInstanceState? Looking at v24 of the support lib...

Comment: so anyone know how to implement this for listview?

Comment: This works on a single `RecyclerView` but not if you have a `ViewPager` with a `RecycerView` on each page.

Comment: @Ivan, I think it works in a fragment (just checked), but not in `onCreateView`, but after data loading. See @Farmaker answer here.

Comment: @Gökhan Barış Aker I have a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176812/android-restore-recyclerview-item-positions-after-app-re-opens.  I would appreciate any insights you have on how to solve.

Comment: @Ivan, in order for this to work in your **Fragment** ensure your saving the new layout state after the data is added to your adapter and not within `onViewStateRestored`.  This worked for me. **ie:** ` adapter.submitList(homeContentList)
                    if (!homeContentList.isEmpty()) {
                        contentRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
                        emptyContent.visibility = GONE
                        contentRecyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(this.savedRecyclerLayoutState)
                    }`

Comment: What if you're not using a Fragment?

Comment: @Ivan Currently, adding `<activity [..] android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">` to AndroidManifest.xml works

Comment: as recyclerview is still in alpha it is the best answer.

Comment: doesnt not work with gridview

Answer (score 101):

Store

```
lastFirstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Restore

```
((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);
```

and if that doesn't work, try

```
((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(lastFirstVisiblePosition,0)
```

Put store in `onPause()`
and restore in `onResume()`

Comment: This works, but you may need to reset the `lastFirstVisiblePosition` to `0` after restoring it. This case is useful when you have a fragment/activity that loads different data in one `RecyclerView`, for example, a file explorer app.

Comment: Excellent! It satisfies both coming back from a detail activity to the list, and saving state on screen rotation

Comment: what to do if my recyclerView is in `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: Why would the first restore option not work, but the second would?

Comment: What is rv? I'm having problems.

Comment: @MehranJalili it seems to be a `RecyclerView`

Comment: ``scrollToPosition`` doesn't need cast to linearlayoutmanager

Comment: This solution will not work if you have large enough list items so that it can be the case the that no list item is completely visible. The "findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()" method will return -1.

Comment: that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 28):

I wanted to save Recycler View's scroll position when navigating away from my list activity and then clicking the back button to navigate back. Many of the solutions provided for this problem were either much more complicated than needed or didn't work for my configuration, so I thought I'd share my solution.

First save your instance state in onPause as many have shown. I think it's worth emphasizing here that this version of onSaveInstanceState is a method from the RecyclerView.LayoutManager class.

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
Parcelable state;

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            state = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
        }
```

The key to getting this to work properly is to make sure you call onRestoreInstanceState after you attach your adapter, as some have indicated in other threads. However the actual method call is much simpler than many have indicated.

```
private void someMethod() {
    mVenueRecyclerView.setAdapter(mVenueAdapter);
    mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

Comment: That's the accurate solution. :D

Comment: for me onSaveInstanceState isnt called so saving state in onPause seems like a better option. im also poping the backstack to return to the fragment.

Comment: for the load in of state. which i do in onViewCreated. it only seems to work when im in debug mode and use break points? or if i add a delay and put the execution in a coroutine.

Answer (score 24):

**Update:** Since version [1.2.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.2.0-alpha02) there's a new API to control when state restoration (including scroll position) happens.

> **`RecyclerView.Adapter` lazy state restoration:**
>
> Added a new API to the RecyclerView.Adapter class which allows Adapter to control when the layout state should be restored.
>
> For example, you can call:
>
> ```java
> myAdapter.setStateRestorationStrategy(StateRestorationStrategy.WHEN_NOT_EMPTY);
> ```
>
> to make RecyclerView wait until Adapter is not empty before restoring the scroll position.

See also:

- [RecyclerView.Adapter#setStateRestorationPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#setstaterestorationpolicy)
- [RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy)

---

**All layout managers bundled in the support library already know how to save and restore scroll position.**

**The `RecyclerView`/`ScrollView`/whatever needs to have an `android:id` for its state to be saved.**

By default, scroll position is restored on the first layout pass which happens when the following conditions are met:

- a layout manager is attached to the `RecyclerView`
- an adapter is attached to the `RecyclerView`

Typically you set the layout manager in XML so all you have to do now is

1. **Load the adapter with data**
2. ***Then* attach the adapter to the `RecyclerView`**

You can do this at any time, it's not constrained to `Fragment.onCreateView` or `Activity.onCreate`.

Example: Ensure the adapter is attached every time the data is updated.

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(this) {
    // Load adapter.
    adapter.data = it

    if (list.adapter != adapter) {
        // Only set the adapter if we didn't do it already.
        list.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

---

The saved scroll position is calculated from the following data:

- Adapter position of the first item on the screen
- Pixel offset of the top of the item from the top of the list (for vertical layout)

Therefore you can expect a slight mismatch e.g. if your items have different dimensions in portrait and landscape orientation.

Comment: This was it for me. I was setting the adapter initially then updating its data when available. As explained above, leaving it until data available makes it automatically scroll back to where it was.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen. Is there any documentation on LayoutManager's saving and restoring scroll position?

Comment: @AdamHurwitz What kind of documentation would you expect? What I described is an implementation detail of LinearLayoutManager, so read its source code.

Comment: Here's a link to `LinearLayoutManager.SavedState`: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java;l=2396

Comment: Thanks, @EugenPechanec. This worked for me for device rotations. I'm also using a bottom navigation view and when I switch to another bottom tab and come back, the list starts from the beginning again. Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: @schv09 Last time I checked bottom nav docs it's supposed to start at top. You would have to save and restore view hierarchy state or fragment state manually.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, that's still the case unfortunately. But it seems to be a bit of work, so I'll wait for the Navigation component to provide this functionality to implement it in my app. Maybe it'll be more streamlined then.

Answer (score 22):

I Set variables in onCreate(), save scroll position in onPause() and set scroll position in onResume()

```
public static int index = -1;
public static int top = -1;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Set Variables
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cRecyclerView = ( RecyclerView )findViewById(R.id.conv_recycler);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    cRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    cRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    //read current recyclerview position
    index = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    View v = cRecyclerView.getChildAt(0);
    top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - cRecyclerView.getPaddingTop());
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //set recyclerview position
    if(index != -1)
    {
        mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset( index, top);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep offset of item too. Nice. Thanks!

Comment: This is not correct. You have to add margin of a view (CardView) too. I have tested this.

Answer (score 15):

You don't have to save and restore the state by yourself anymore. If you set unique ID in xml and recyclerView.setSaveEnabled(true) (true by default) system will automatically do it.
Here is more about this: http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/

Answer (score 15):

Beginning from version 1.2.0-alpha02 of androidx recyclerView library, it is now automatically managed. Just add it with:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02"
```

And use:

```
adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

The StateRestorationPolicy enum has 3 options:

- ALLOW — the default state, that restores the RecyclerView state immediately, in the next layout pass
- PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY — restores the RecyclerView state only when the adapter is not empty (adapter.getItemCount() > 0). If your data is loaded async, the RecyclerView waits until data is loaded and only then the state is restored. If you have default items, like headers or load progress indicators as part of your Adapter, then you should use the PREVENT option, unless the default items are added using [MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter). MergeAdapter waits for all of its adapters to be ready and only then it restores the state.
- PREVENT — all state restoration is deferred until you set ALLOW or PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY.

Note that at the time of this answer, recyclerView library is still in alpha03, but **alpha phase is not suitable for production purposes**.

Comment: So much overwork saved. Else we had to save list click index, restore elements, prevent redrawing in onCreateView, apply  scrollToPosition (or do as other answers) and yet the user could notice the difference after coming back

Comment: Also, If I want to save RecyclerView position after navigation through app ... is there some tool for it?

Comment: @RubenViguera Why alpha is not for production purposes? I mean is that really bad?

Comment: @StayCool "Also, If I want to save RecyclerView position after navigation through app ... is there some tool for it?" Then I guess your fragments aren't being restored properly by Navigation library. You should review your code because your fragments are likely to be recreated on every movement, and not restored.

Comment: @StayCool "Why alpha is not for production purposes? I mean is that really bad?" Alpha is a term used for software being in development, its API is suitable to changes, and highly probable of having bugs (unstable). Beta term is used for software being in testing state. I mean, is a software in a process of stabilization where no new features are developed and just bugs are fixed. Release Candidate term is for software in a final state of testing. If no more critial bugs appears is the candidate to be the next stable (production) version.

Comment: I don't do anything special with navigation controller so my fragments will be recreated every time... I usually use inclusive  popUpTo  to mainNav when I don't want backstack contain e.g. login screen after successfull login. Also, I use a lot inclusive popUpTo  fragment_x when I don't want 2 fragments loop between each other

Comment: @RubénViguera thanks for the answers. About Alpha I knew that for sure, I just thought that recycler view has pretty solid reliability when I used it. Everything worked fine

Comment: There is an issue with this API. In fact if you have registered listener, the onscroll callback will be invoked with 0 deltas when the adapter restores the state during the next frame.

Answer (score 10):

Since I find that most options are too long or complicated, here is my short **Kotlin** option with **viewBinding** and **viewModel** for achieving this:

If you want to have your RecyclerView state lifecycle aware, put this code in your ViewModel, otherwise you can use a basic Repository and work from there:

```
private lateinit var state: Parcelable
fun saveRecyclerViewState(parcelable: Parcelable) { state = parcelable }
fun restoreRecyclerViewState() : Parcelable = state
fun stateInitialized() : Boolean = ::state.isInitialized
```

and this inside your ***onPause()***

```
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()?.let { viewModel.saveRecyclerViewState(it) }
```

and finally this in your ***onResume()***

```
if (viewModel.stateInitialized()) {
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(
            viewModel.restoreRecyclerViewState()
        )
    }
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same requirement, but the solutions here didn't quite get me across the line, due to the source of data for the recyclerView.

I was extracting the RecyclerViews' LinearLayoutManager state in onPause()

```
private Parcelable state;

Public void onPause() {
    state = mLinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
}
```

Parcelable `state` is saved in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`, and extracted again in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, when `savedInstanceState != null`.

However, the recyclerView adapter is populated and updated by a ViewModel LiveData object returned by a DAO call to a Room database.

```
mViewModel.getAllDataToDisplay(mSelectedData).observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<String> displayStrings) {
        mAdapter.swapData(displayStrings);
        mLinearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
});
```

I eventually found that restoring the instance state directly after the data is set in the adapter would keep the scroll-state across rotations.

I suspect this either is because the `LinearLayoutManager` state that I'd restored was being overwritten when the data was returned by the database call, or the restored state was meaningless against an 'empty' LinearLayoutManager.

If the adapter data is available directly (ie not contigent on a database call), then restoring the instance state on the LinearLayoutManager can be done after the adapter is set on the recyclerView.

The distinction between the two scenarios held me up for ages.

Comment: this is actually still usable even after the update which used recyclerview policy, in cases you need to manually save the state of the recyclerview for example if you have horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview, the inner recyclerview will never save its scroll position so you need to manually do like in the answer. and save the state inside onViewRecycled and set it again in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: here is link to how to include recyclerview inside other with different layout-manger orientation https://medium.com/@gsaillen95/how-to-inflate-different-layoutmanagers-for-each-adapter-with-concatadapter-76cdee6266ca

Answer (score 5):

Here is my Approach to save them and maintain the state of recyclerview in a fragment.
First, add config changes in your parent activity as below code.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Then in your Fragment declare these instance method's

```
private  Bundle mBundleRecyclerViewState;
private Parcelable mListState = null;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
```

Add below code in your @onPause method

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //This used to store the state of recycler view
    mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
    mListState =mTrailersRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(getResources().getString(R.string.recycler_scroll_position_key), mListState);
}
```

Add onConfigartionChanged Method like below.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //When orientation is changed then grid column count is also changed so get every time
    Log.e(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: " );
    if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(getResources().getString(R.string.recycler_scroll_position_key));
                mTrailersRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);

            }
        }, 50);
    }
    mTrailersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
}
```

This approch will reslove your problem.
if You have diffrent layout manager then just replace upper layout manager.

Comment: You may not need a Handler for persisting data. Lifecycle methods will be sufficient enough for saving/loading.

Comment: @sayaMahi Can you describe in a proper way. I  also have seen that onConfigurationChanged prevent to call on the destroy method. so it is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 4):

On Android API Level 28, I simply ensure that I set up my `LinearLayoutManager` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` in my `Fragment#onCreateView` method, and everything Just Worked™️. I didn't need to do any `onSaveInstanceState` or `onRestoreInstanceState` work.

[Eugen Pechanec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54461502/9636) explains why this works.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I restore RecyclerView position with GridLayoutManager after rotation when you need to reload data from internet with AsyncTaskLoader.

Make a global variable of Parcelable and GridLayoutManager and a static final string:

```
private Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState;
private GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager;
private static final String BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT = "recycler_layout";
```

Save state of gridLayoutManager in onSaveInstance()

```
 @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT, 
            mGridLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState());
        }
```

Restore in onRestoreInstanceState

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        //restore recycler view at same position
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            savedRecyclerLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT);
        }
    }
```

Then when loader fetches data from internet you restore recyclerview position in onLoadFinished()

```
if(savedRecyclerLayoutState!=null){
                mGridLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
            }
```

..of course you have to instantiate gridLayoutManager inside onCreate.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I set up a new layoutmanager every time I changed my adapter, loosing que scroll position on recyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY` which is introduced in `recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02`

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334

but it has some issues such as not working with inner RecyclerView, and some other issues you can check out in medium post's comment section.

Or you can use `ViewModel` with `SavedStateHandle` which works for inner RecyclerViews, screen rotation and **process death**.

Create a `ViewModel` with `saveStateHandle`

```
val scrollState=
    savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Parcelable?>(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE)
```

use Parcelable `scrollState` to save and restore state as answered in other posts or by adding a scroll listener to RecyclerView and

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
               scrollState.value = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to share the recent predicament I encounter with the RecyclerView. I hope that anyone experiencing the same problem will benefit.

My Project Requirement:
So I have a RecyclerView that list some clickable items in my Main Activity (Activity-A). When the Item is clicked a new Activity is shown with the Item Details (Activity-B).

**I implemented in the Manifest** file the that the Activity-A is the parent of Activity-B, that way, I have a back or home button on the ActionBar of the Activity-B

Problem:
Every time I pressed the Back or Home button in the Activity-B ActionBar, the Activity-A goes into the full Activity Life Cycle starting from onCreate()

Even though I implemented an onSaveInstanceState() saving the List of the RecyclerView's Adapter, when Activity-A starts it's lifecycle, the saveInstanceState is always null in the onCreate() method.

Further digging in the internet, I came across the same problem but the person noticed that the Back or Home button below the Anroid device (Default Back/Home button), the Activity-A does not goes into the Activity Life-Cycle.

Solution:

1. I removed the  Tag for Parent Activity in the manifest for Activity-B
2. I enabled the home or back button on Activity-B

   Under onCreate() method add this line **supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)**
3. In the overide fun onOptionsItemSelected() method, I checked for the item.ItemId   on which item is clicked based on the id. The Id for the back button is

   **android.R.id.home**

   Then implement a finish() function call inside the android.R.id.home

   This will end the Activity-B and bring Acitivy-A without going through the entire life-cycle.

For my requirement this is the best solution so far.

```
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_project)

    supportActionBar?.title = projectName
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}


 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    when(item?.itemId){

        android.R.id.home -> {
            finish()
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a minor difference, I was using **Databinding**, and I was setting recyclerView adapter and the layoutManager in the binding methods.

The problem was that data-binding was happening after **onResume** so it was resetting my layoutManager after onResume and that means it was scrolling back to original place every time.
So when I stopped setting layoutManager in Databinding adaptor methods, it works fine again.

Comment: how did you achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5jDe7NogAM),

First of all, define variables,

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
int lastPosition;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES__DISPLAY = "MyPrefs_display" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences_display;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor_display;
```

then,

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(sharedpreferences_display.getInt("last_saved_position", 0));

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        lastPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }
});
```

if you want to save position by button,

```
btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    editor_display.putInt("last_saved_position", lastPosition).apply();
    Toast.makeText(Arama_Fav_Activity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting the RecyclerView's `layoutManager` both in XML and in `onViewCreated`. Removing the assignment in `onViewCreated` fixed it.

```
with(_binding.list) {
//  layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = MyAdapter().apply {
        listViewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer {
                it?.let { setItems(it) }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Activity.java:**

```
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

Parcelable state;

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


// Inside `onCreate()` lifecycle method, put the below code :

    if(state != null) {
    mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (state != null) {
            mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
    }   

   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        state = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();

    }
```

Why I'm using `OnSaveInstanceState()` in `onPause()` means, While switch to another activity onPause would be called.It will save that scroll position and restore the position when we coming back from another activity.

Comment: The Public static field is not good. Global data and singletons are not good.

Comment: @weston I understood now.I changed savingstate to onpause to remove global.