# RecyclerView store / restore state between activities

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm migrating my ListViews to RecyclerViews. With listviews I used the common technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview/5688490#5688490) to store and restore scroll position between activities.

How to do the same with RecyclerViews? the `RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState()` seem to have `protected` access, so can't be used directly.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Ok, so to answer my own question. As I understand it, since they've decoupled the layout code and the view recycling code (thus the name), the component responsible one for holding layout state (and restoring it) is now the `LayoutManager` used in your recyclerview.

Thus, to store state you use same pattern, but on the **layout manager** and not the recyclerview:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

     // Save list state
     mListState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
     state.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, mListState);
}
```

Restore state in the `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    // Retrieve list state and list/item positions
    if(state != null)
        mListState = state.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
}
```

Then update the LayoutManager (I do in `onResume()`):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mListState != null) {
        mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if `onRestoreInstanceState()` is never called ?

Comment: Hi, would your code above help me with a RecyclerView list where instancestate is not being saved between activities? I posted the following question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413495/android-how-do-i-return-to-newly-created-recyclerview-list

Comment: @AJW the best way to answer would be to run it.

Comment: But what about adapter?

Comment: You can streamline your onRestoreInstanceState() further by eliminating the null check. As per Android documentation: "The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null". 
This is not me nitpicking or anything.

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `state.getParcelable` with the parameter `LIST_STATE_KEY` rather than `"myState"`?

Comment: @JonMcClung yes. Actually in my code they both had this value, so I haven't paid attention when answering. But, it would be correct to use same variables.

Comment: If you're using a `Fragment`, instead of restoring the state on `onRestoreInstanceState`, you can safely do it on `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: @khusrav I have recyclerView whose state I want put into savedInstance state but whenever I try to restore its state it gives me error that it is null. I am following same code of yours.

Comment: @khusrav I have a similar issue here: stackoverflow.com/questions/52176812/…. I would appreciate any insights you have on how to solve.

Comment: @AJW for a similar table, I have a special column called 'position' - it represents the order in which items should be shown. When drag-n-dropping, I change the values of the position of the item dragged and all others affected.

Comment: @khusrav Ok I understand.  Do you save the positions in a database or an ArrayList or SparseArray using onSaveInstanceState() and then onRestoreInstanceState()?  And then retrieve the database position or Array in onResume() or onCreate()?

Comment: What is "mListState"

Comment: @MML Parceable, as in the cross-linked question

Answer (score 20):

**I found a better solution** - this solution has the following benefits :

1. RecyclerView state is saved and restored on **rotation of phone**
2. RecyclerView state is saved and restored on **returning to activity** with RecyclerView (which wasn't destroyed whilst the other activity was showing - which means that `onRestoreInstanceState()` isn't called !!)

**CODE**

```
public class ActivityItemList extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private final String KEY_RECYCLER_STATE = "recycler_state";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private static Bundle mBundleRecyclerViewState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);//set to whatever layout name you have

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);//set to whatever view id you use
        // don't forget to set your adapter
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        // save RecyclerView state
        mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
        Parcelable listState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
        mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, listState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // restore RecyclerView state
        if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
            Parcelable listState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
            mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, would your code above help me with a RecyclerView list where instancestate is not being saved between activities?  I posted the following question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413495/android-how-do-i-return-to-newly-created-recyclerview-list?

Comment: I added your code above to my RecyclerView activity with no luck.  When going to a previous activity and then returning to the newly created RecyclerView list, the list of new items is lost and I only see the default list layout.

Comment: Why do you save the state in `onPause()`? At this time the activity is not destroyed. The state is intact. There's nothing to restore.

Comment: out of frustration because I've had moments of OnSaveInstanceState() not being called :/

Comment: I was doing some additional research and discovered in Google's sample code that it's probably much better to simply save and restore the scroll position instead of serializing the manager's state. See \sdk\samples\android-21\ui\views\RecyclerView\Application\src\main\java\com\example\android\recyclerview\RecyclerViewFragment.java

Comment: Using static variables to save state during configuration changes is blasphemy in the Android world. You should definitely use the lifecycle from Android which is designed precisely for this task.

Comment: This will work, but you don't have to use a static reference. You can just store it in the bundle of onSaveInstanceState, and restore it in onCreate.

Comment: yeah, I do it like that now. However, when I made this post I observed `OnSaveInstanceState()` not being called.

Comment: @Someone Somewhere I have a similar issue here: stackoverflow.com/questions/52176812/…. I would appreciate any insights you have on how to solve.

Comment: This solution works with ViewModel. if we need to save state of view, located in Fragment, we need to bind ViewModel in activity and save/restore states from variables from ViewModel. And we don't need any static variables =)

Answer (score 16):

Use this code in `onPause()` and `onResume()` to save and restore scroll position-

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
recyclerViewState = mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();//save
mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);//restore
```

Comment: it looks like something is missing here because recyclerViewState is never saved anywhere

Comment: You can save it any way you want, depending on how you want to implement it.

Answer (score 9):

That's my solution, it restores both items and RecyclerView position

1) save recycler view state in onSaveInstanceState method

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Parcelable listState = myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    // putting recyclerview position
    outState.putParcelable(SAVED_RECYCLER_VIEW_STATUS_ID, listState);
    // putting recyclerview items
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(SAVED_RECYCLER_VIEW_DATASET_ID,mDataset);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

2) Check savedInstanceState Bundle in onCreate method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            getRemoteData(); // No saved data, get data from remote
        }else{
            restorePreviousState(); // Restore data found in the Bundle
        }
    }
```

3) Restore recycler view data if the screen has been rotated

```
public void restorePreviousState(){
    // getting recyclerview position
    mListState = mSavedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_RECYCLER_VIEW_STATUS_ID);
    // getting recyclerview items
    mDataset = mSavedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SAVED_RECYCLER_VIEW_DATASET_ID);
    // Restoring adapter items
    mAdapter.setItems(mDataset);
    // Restoring recycler view position
    mRvMedia.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't save your dataset with savedInstanceState.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#viewmodel_vs_savedinstancestate

Comment: Thanks for the hint @jakk, I'll give ViewModel class a try!

Comment: ViewModel is a bad idea. Be careful if you want to use it. https://www.techyourchance.com/android-viewmodel-architecture-component-harmful/

Comment: Thanks for your hint @Kalinga. Did you have bad experience with ViewModel?

Comment: No. I have decided not to use it, as it adds more code bloat instead of aiding you & does not address save/restore flow, which you have to address in anycase. Once you implement save/restore, there is no real advantage of using ViewModel

Comment: I attended the Udacity Android Nanodegree developer program and during the course the ViewModel was not mentioned despite the "SavedInstanceState" method, so I guess the second one is the right thing to do in this cases

Comment: @Nicola Gallazzi In your #2 above, what is mSavedInstanceState defined as?

Comment: @AJW thanks for the question, that was a mistake. I edited the answer replacing mSavedInstanceState with savedInstanceState coming from onCreate method

Comment: @Nicola Gallazzi Ok, understood and thank you for the clarification.

Comment: mAdapter.setItems(mDataset); my adapter doesn't have a setItem  method

Comment: @AcauãPitta it's a simple setter of your adapter dataset, like you do in a normal POJO class

Answer (score 3):

I know i am late but still if it helps!!

Storing the recycler view position is lot simpler than what other answers have made it look like

Here's how you can do it

First create a member variable

```
Parcelable state;
```

Now,

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    state = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

overide on pause and on resume methods with the above code and you are good to go!!

Comment: This is by far the cleanest way

Comment: ok I have tried it but it's not working for me , can you help me with this

Comment: @vasant Are you sure you are using this in an activity

Comment: nope I'm using in fragment

Comment: @vasant ig thats where the problem is maybe we can't use this method in fragments

Comment: This will only work when reusing same instance of activity/fragment so never do this. It won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY` which is introduced in `recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02`

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334

but it has some issues such as not working with inner RecyclerView, and some other issues you can check out in medium post's comment section.

Or you can use `ViewModel` with `SavedStateHandle` which works for inner RecyclerViews, screen rotation and **process death**.

Create a `ViewModel` with `saveStateHandle`

```
val scrollState=
    savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Parcelable?>(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE)
```

use Parcelable `scrollState` to save and restore state as answered in other posts or by adding a scroll listener to RecyclerView and

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

```
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
           // save here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer - much better than using save instance state. Recyclerview is now in beta also: recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02

Comment: This is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState()` don't forget to check for **null**:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if (recyclerView != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(SCROLL_POSITION, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Parcelable recyclerViewState;
.......
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        recyclerViewState = MainAnecdotesView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();//save
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(recyclerViewState!=null)
            MainAnecdotesView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);//restore
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Considering that you defined a RecyclerView (`mRecyclerView`) and a LayoutManager (`mLayoutManager`) in your code and all is working fine so far, the solution on saving the position (`mPosition`) of your RecyclerView looks like this:

1. Variables and constants used:

   ```
   private final String RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY = "recycler_position";
   private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
   private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
   private static Bundle mBundleState;
   ```
2. In `onPause` method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause()
   {
       super.onPause();

       // Save RecyclerView state
       mBundleState = new Bundle();
       mPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
       mBundleState.putInt(RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY, mPosition);
   }
   ```
3. In `onResume` method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
       super.onResume();

       // Restore RecyclerView state
       if (mBundleState != null) {
           mPosition = mBundleState.getInt(RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY);
           if (mPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) mPosition = 0;
           // Scroll the RecyclerView to mPosition
           mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);
       }
   }
   ```
4. In `onSaveInstanceState` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       // Save RecyclerView state
       outState.putInt(RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY,  mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());

       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   }
   ```
5. In `onRestoreInstanceState` method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Restore RecyclerView state
       if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY)) {
           mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(RECYCLER_POSITION_KEY);
           if (mPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) mPosition = 0;
           // Scroll the RecyclerView to mPosition
           mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);
       }

       super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't store your state in static variable, that is bad practice and it will break your code.