# Fragment's restored instanceState bundle is always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to save my Recyclerview's LinearLayoutManager state.

**Fragment.java :**

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i("frag", "onSaveInstanceState called");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("myState", mGridLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState());
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "restore called from createView");
                mGridLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("myState"));
            }
          .....
          ....
    }
```

But `savedInstanceState` is always null.

I already tried to restore its state in the **onCreate** & **onActivityCreated** methods, but in vain. What am I doing wrong ?

I checked these questions to be certain that this is the correct way to save & restore :

[Recyclerview store / save state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities)

[Save recyclerview scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerview-scroll-position-with-recyclerview-state-or-no)

Comment: read this [how to fragment save states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787071/android-fragment-how-to-save-states-of-views-in-a-fragment-when-another-fragmen) I give up using save states of fragment :(

Comment: I did the exact same thing but it didn't work... I started to think that it's because I'm using the support library

Answer (score 0):

try putting your call to super.onSaveInstanceState(outstate) after you call outstate.putParcelable()?

If that doesn't work, maybe try just putting a string in the bundle and see if it has something to do with your mGridLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState() failing?

Comment: did you move the call to super after you modified the outState?

Comment: well i just checked some of my code and my calls to super() are like yours, so nevermind on that.

Comment: I catch it in onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: wonder if you could be passing a different bundle to this fragment when you navigate to it and maybe it clashes with the one created in onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: I don't think so because I use a static method to instantiate the fragment. Could it be a 'Fragment' or 'app.v4.Fragment' issue ?

Comment: sorry man idk, you should try making a new default project in android studio and have it instantiate a fragment for you. and then test the onSaveInstanceState() and onCreate() and see if it work there, then slowly move it towards your implementation till you find the bug.

Comment: I shall give it a try. Thanks