# Why does RecyclerView restore its state after rotation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager, screen-rotation, savestate

I have `RecyclerView` inside `Fragment` handled by `ViewPager`. How is it made that RecyclerView **automatically** restore its state after rotation? I thought I have to implement

```
LayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()
LayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state);
```

by myself. Is `LayoutManager` or `RecyclerView` register some kind of `onConfigurationChange` receiver?

Comment: Look this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities

Comment: No, neither LayoutManger nor RecyclerView will receive onconfigurationchage.

Comment: @BenjaminBihr It says nothing about my question. I'm asking why restoring the state working by defualt, without implementing it explicitly.

Comment: @keyur9779 useless comment

Comment: @AppiDevo I think you should check your question once again, as i didn't find any why in your entire question. so I answered your last question  only.

Answer (score 2):

A RecyclerView extends a ViewGroup so, it's extend a View.

If you put an Id on your RecyclerView, the

> onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState

will be call.

Link : [RecyclerView store / restore state between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities)

Comment: As I said earlier there are no information about my question in the link you posted. Here is helpful link: http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/ with great explanation how AUTOMATIC state saving works.

Comment: Ok ! Your question is not only for recyclerView if I understand correctly