# Returning to same recycler view position after coming from other activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one recycler view, when clicking on the Recycler view item it goes to some other activity. Again if I come back from that activity to Main activity, I should show the same recycler view position. I cant use finish() , in this case. If i am using finish then I can able to be in the same recycler view position. But in my case i cant use that. After come back from second activity i need to refresh the api again to update the values, so if finish the activity i cant get the Api changes. And i tried to do by calling OnRestoresavedInstance state, but in that case I am facing null pointer exception. Is there any way to get back the same recycler view poistion when i am coming from second activity? i Used this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities) to sort out my problem. But doesn't find any result.

please help me out of this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could store the index in SharedPreferences. Then, in the onResume method of the first activity, retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

First save the position of recycler view in shared prefernces

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("SNOW_DENSITY",mSnowDensity);
editor.commit();
```

And then when you come back just fetch the value

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
int snowDensity = settings.getInt("SNOW_DENSITY", 0); //0 is the default value
```

And now simple move to position in recycler view

```
 mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(firstCounter - 1);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry! Didnt get you completely. What values i have to give in editor.putInt ? mSnowDensity is which value?

Comment: Not working. I tried this. In onResume I am fetching the value

Comment: its the position of recycler view

Comment: what re you getting?? when you are fetching the value

Comment: and when getting from shared preferences what are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144449/discussion-between-abdul-kawee-and-yamuna).

Comment: and is your activity destroying or is paused?

Comment: Its in paused state