# Where use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

This is a conceptual issue. Sorry if it is a simple question, I start to learn Android few days ago.

I was trying to save the state of a recyclerview when the user out of the activity. And I read some articles about this.

In this article https://panavtec.me/retain-restore-recycler-view-scroll-position the methods are :

```
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState();
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state);
```

In this other article [RecyclerView store / restore state between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) the methods are:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state)
```

These two articles pretend to answer the same question, how to restore the state of a recyclerview.

---

Questions:

1 - The first article implements these methods on a layoutManager!? So, I'm using a default GridLayoutManager, so to implement save and restore instance in the GridLayoutManager I should create my own class extending the default class?

2 - I can implement these methods in the layoutmanager regardless of implementing them in the activity?

3 - Where is the correct place to implement these methods? or is there a official answer to the question: "How restore the state of a recyclerview?"

I am looking for opinions on these three questions, not a full implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - The first article implements these methods on a layoutManager!?
>   So, I'm using a default GridLayoutManager, so to implement save and
>   restore instance in the GridLayoutManager I should create my own class
>   extending the default class?

If you look at both the article and the SO post they do not *implement* anything inside the `LayoutManager`, they just use methods that already exist.
If you look in the documentation page for the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) there are already both a `onSaveInstanceState()` and a `onRestoreInstanceState (Parcelable state)` methods (these two methods are the "convenient API" the blog mentions at the start).

As I'm sure you've noticed `GridLayoutManager` inherits from `LinearLayoutManager`
official documentation of [LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#onSaveInstanceState()):

> Called when the LayoutManager should save its state. [...] Returns:
>   Parcelable Necessary information for LayoutManager to be able to restore its
>   state

official documentation of [LinearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState (Parcelable state)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable))
Very incomplete but you can tell that it uses the same `Parcelable` parameter returned by LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()

> 2 - I can implement these methods in the layoutmanager regardless of
>   implementing them in the activity?

To be clear: no need to re-implement the LayoutManager. I don't see why you would need to do that, the methods are there and ready to use.
The Activity methods of the same name are what you need to implement.

> 3 - Where is the correct place to implement these methods? or is there
>   a official answer to the question: "How restore the state of a
>   recyclerview?"

The correct place to do this is the Activity's lifecycle methods, these will be called at the appropriate times to save and restore your `LayoutManager` state.
Quoting the SO answer you mentioned:

```
//---> this is the Activity's onSaveInstanceState
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

     // Save list state
     mListState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
     state.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, mListState);
}

//---> this is the Activity's onRestoreInstanceState
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    // Retrieve list state and list/item positions
    if(state != null)
        mListState = state.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
}

//---> this is the Activity's onResume
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mListState != null) {
        mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    }
}
```

I haven't seen any official documentation about *specifically* restoring the RecyclerView/LayoutManager state but the [lifecycle subject](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java) is a very important one in Android. I believe that after fully understanding this one can make the right decisions regarding specific use-cases.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, could you answer me, why I when try to use the signature "protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()" with @Override anotation (like the link in the question) I receive "Method does not override method from its superclass" (I'm trying to use this signature on a Activity). But when I use this signature "protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)" all works fine?

Comment: @romeuBraga yeah I think you might be confusing the two signatures (which is understandable since the methods have the same name) - the correct Activity signature is the one here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

The first one doesn't work because You are trying to override the LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState() method - in other words this method does not exist in the Activity class ;)