# Preventing recyclerview from reloading after returning back from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm a newbie here.
I'm using bottomnavigationview in my activity(say Activity1) with three fragments. One of them contains `Recyclerview` which loads data from firebase and on click leads to another activity(say Activity2) using intents and passes some data with it. Now when I press back in Activity2 it returns to Activity1 which is what I want and fine, but the problem is that the `Recyclerview` reloads again.
PS. I tried to put a button in another fragment(Just for testing purpose) which leads to same activity and on returning back from it, the activity1 retains the position, data and doesn't reload. So I guess the problem is with `Recyclerview` onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it,I had my adapter ".startlistening()" in onStart() method,I simply placed it in onCreateView() before setting up recyclerview adapter and removed onStop() method.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried saving and restoring your recyclerView's data in [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) in [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))? You can also save the recyclerView scroll state as well using the linearLayoutManager.

Here's an example of how to save the recyclerView's state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262885/4138919

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove OnResume() method. I think you are fetching data from server or database when fragment starts. So make sure not calling data on onResume() method.