# Save RecyclerView state after AsyncTask call when returning from second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner in mobile app development and very keen to do things the right way.

In this scenario I call an `AsycTask` to populate my `RecycleView` with data in the first activity.

When an item is clicked in the `RecycleView` I start a second activity.
When the back button is clicked from here I go back to the first activity.
It is at this point that I need to have the same data displayed in the `RecycleView` as right at the start.

How do I achieve this?

The code from **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variables for the search input field, and results TextViews.

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private WordListAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinkedList<String> mWordList = new LinkedList<>();

    /**
     * Initializes the activity.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The current state data
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize all the view variables.

        mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        searchBooks(new View(this));
    }

    /**
     * Gets called when the user pushes the "Search Books" button
     *
     * @param view The view (Button) that was clicked.
     */
    public void searchBooks(View view) {
        // Get the search string from the input field.
        //String queryString = mBookInput.getText().toString();


        // Check the status of the network connection.
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If the network is active and the search field is not empty, start a FetchBook AsyncTask.
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new FetchBook(mWordList).execute("Titanic");

            try { Thread.sleep(5000); }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) { android.util.Log.d("YourApplicationName", ex.toString()); }

            // Create recycler view.
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            // Create an adapter and supply the data to be displayed.
            mAdapter = new WordListAdapter(this, mWordList);
            // Connect the adapter with the recycler view.
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            // Give the recycler view a default layout manager.
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
        // Otherwise update the TextView to tell the user there is no connection or no search term.
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now realised that the back button which was implemented in the Manifest file fired the onDestroy method. However, using the UP button the activity wasn't destroyed and the data in the RecycleView was retained.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you will have to use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() within the activity. Pass the respective key value pairs on onSaveInstanceState() then retrieve the  values on onRestoreInstanceState(); Check the link below for detailed explanation and code: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262885/5985401][1]