# Android: RecyclerView GridLayoutManager - Restoring scroll position doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate

I have 3 activities: 
A --> B --> C

In Activity B, I'm populating using RecyclerView's GridlayoutManager. I want to save the scrolled state when i navigate to Activity C and restore the scrolled state when i go back to Activity B from Activity C.

```
private RecyclerView mImgList;
private GridLayoutManager mRecyclerGridMan;
private final String KEY_RECYCLER_STATE = "recycler_state";
private Parcelable mListState = null;
private static Bundle mBundleRecyclerViewState;
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
    mListState = mImgList.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, mListState);
}
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
        mListState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
        mImgList.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    }
}
```

But this works when I press back button from Activity B and go to Activity A, and navigating back to Activity B from Activity A.

Comment: have you checked that your `mBundleRecyclerViewState` is really not `null` ?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes i checked, mBundleRecyclerViewState is not null when im coming back from Activity C to Activity B.

Comment: Do you populate your list again after coming back to activity?

Comment: you may try doing `onRestoreInstanceState` in a Handler. I'm not sure if it helps, but it might.

Comment: @VygintasB Yes, my code for populating is inside onStart() method. onRestart(), onStart(), onResume() these methods are called when i come back from Activity C to B.

Comment: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() are called when navigate to Activity A to B.

Comment: Please refer the following. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236390/recyclerview-store-restore-state-between-activities

Comment: @ParamaSudha i tried the accepted answer in that link, but not working in my case. :-(

Comment: Find the first visible item position. Then, scroll recyclerview to that position. Take a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36569778/5392118).

Comment: @BurakCakir Brother I have tried that already even before I'm posting this question.

Comment: Here's the link to complete code: https://github.com/zayid/Blur_Wallpaper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/whackyard/whatsappwalls/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Restore state in the onRestoreInstanceState()

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

// Retrieve list state and list/item positions
if(state != null)
   mListState =   mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but not working. Even the scroll state is not restored when navigating to Activity A to B, which was working before.

Comment: Here's the link to complete code: https://github.com/zayid/Blur_Wallpaper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/whackyard/whatsappwalls/MainActivity.java