# RecyclerView Item track after Item Click to the NextActivity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Am having a `RecyclerView` listing items  so my issue is,suppose when i click on `position 8` item and it goes to the `NextActivity` , when i press the back button , I don't go back to `postion 8` it goes to `position 0`.

How can i make my `RecyclerView` track an Item , so that when I try to go to the `NextActivity` and i press the back button it comes back to the Item which I clicked not position 0?.

Any one who knows this please help.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so simple , the Problem is you are using `OnStart()` to load your data items ,try to use `OnCreate()` to load your data . Then there you will be able to get rid of that problem.

What `OnStart()` does whenever you come back to the Activity which has `OnStart()`, it loads data again , that's why the RecyclerView goes back to item 0.

Answer (score 1):

In your RecyclerView Activity's onPause method store the completely visible item position in your list. Then in onResume method write statement to scroll to that particular position.

Links below will help you
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)

Comment: can you please show me a simple code sample Implementation instead of the docs  thamks

Comment: See the first answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568168/how-to-save-scroll-position-of-recyclerview-in-android

Comment: I have inseted this But when i click on the RecyclerView the App crashes  `@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

         long currentVisiblePosition = 0;
        currentVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerview.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
         int currentVisiblePosition = 0;
        super.onResume();
        ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerview.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(currentVisiblePosition);
        currentVisiblePosition = 0;
    }`