# how to get RecyclerView position for scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that contains a RecyclerView. When I return to the fragment from somewhere else, I do

```
if(null!=savedInstanceState) {
  mScrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ITEM_POSITION);
  mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mScrollPosition);
}
```

but now I don't know what to put inside `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    mScrollPosition=mRecyclerView.getScrollPosition();//???
    bundle.putInt(NITEM_POSITION,mScrollPosition);
}
```

There is no `mRecyclerView.getScrollPosition()`.

**update**

after testing it turns out that using `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition` is not fine enough to ensure a smooth user experience. In cases where the item views are tall enough, `scrollToPosition(ofFirstVisibleItem)` can be way off. So is there a finer solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the scroll from the LayoutManager. For example:

```
 mScrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

also check this answer [How to save RecyclerView's scroll position using RecyclerView.State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerview-scroll-position-with-recyclerview-state-or-no)

Comment: Although you sort of answered the question, it turns out the assumption was wrong. Using scrollToPosition does not actually return the view to where it left: if an item is tall enough, it is very apparent to the user that the position has shifted. So is there a better way to do this instead of using adapter position?

Comment: many thanks. It looks exactly like what I need, but I am not sure where to put what. Sorry, but I am a at that level :). The code does not look like it goes in my fragment, for instance. And there are many parts. I know it's a bit much, but do you mind showing where to put what? I am sure other people here would be grateful as well.

Comment: Sorry for a lot of link, don't have time for detailed answer http://emuneee.com/blog/2013/01/07/saving-fragment-states/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack