# Restore PagedListAdapter position when resuming activity

Tags: android, android-paging

I've been experimenting with `PagedListAdapter` and can't figure out how to restore adapters position correctly.

Last attempt was to save `lastKey` from current list.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    val lastKey = adapter.currentList?.lastKey as Int

    outState.putInt("lastKey", lastKey)
}
```

but when restoring my adapter and passing `lastKey` to `PagedListBuilder` what I last saw and what is being displayed differs by quite a bit.

```
    val dataSourceFactory = dao.reportsDataSourceFactory()
    val builder = RxPagedListBuilder(
        dataSourceFactory,
        PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(60)
            .setPageSize(20)
            .setPrefetchDistance(60)
            .build()
    )
        .setInitialLoadKey(initialLoadKey)
        .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
```

If I'm in the [middle of page #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae3DR.png) when resuming - adapter will be at position at the [beginning of page #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkARq.png). Ideally adapter should be restored in exactly the same position as last seen.

Various attempts to save LayoutManager state

```
outState.putParcelable("layout_manager_state", recycler_view.layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState())
```

and then restore it

```
recycler_view.layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(it.getParcelable("layout_manager_state"))
```

failed miserably. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: What exactly happens when you save/restore state of layoutmanager?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya nothing. As if state is ignored and first item visible is the first item in the page.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerviews-scroll-position-using-recyclerview-state) other options also.

Comment: What do you mean by resuming - adapter? Is there any configuration change (e.g. rotation) or you navigate back to list activity from other activity?

Comment: For example app is sent to background and activity is destroyed. The when resuming state should be restored.

Comment: You mean the case, when your app is in background and system kills your app process due to memory constraints, right?

Comment: Yes. Or of checked "Don't keep activities" in developer settings.

Comment: Are you loading data in a worker thread(Other than UI thread)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working.

Precondition - your `PagedListAdapter` **must support null placeholders**! `setEnablePlaceholders(true)`. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList)

```
    val dataSourceFactory = dao.reportsDataSourceFactory()
    val builder = RxPagedListBuilder(
        dataSourceFactory,
        PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true) //in my original implementation it was false
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(60)
            .setPageSize(20)
            .setPrefetchDistance(60)
            .build()
    )
```

Save state as usual:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    val lastKey = adapter.currentList?.lastKey as Int

    outState.putInt("lastKey", lastKey)
    outState.putParcelable("layout_manager_state", recycler_view.layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState())
}
```

but when restoring - **first save state as variable and only restore saved state after submitting list to the `PagedListAdapter`**

```
private fun showReports(pagedList: PagedList<Report>?) {
    adapter.submitList(pagedList)

    lastLayoutManagerState?.let {
        report_list.layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(lastLayoutManagerState)
        lastLayoutManagerState = null
    }
}
```

where `lastLayoutManagerState` is:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = withViewModel(viewModelFactory) {
        observe(reports, ::showReports)
    }

    report_list.adapter = adapter

    lastLayoutManagerState = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable("layout_manager_state")

    val lastKey = savedInstanceState?.getInt("lastKey")
    viewModel.getReports(lastKey)
}
```

Oh and when binding `ViewHolder` in `onBindViewHolder` I just bail out fast if item is null.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position) ?: return
    ... 
}
```

Because it will be null as otherwise adapter item count won't match with saved state item count (guessing here) and that is why in some of my experiments layout was jumping around on pages 2+ while it worked on page 1.

If there are better ways how to approach this without manually storing and then using `lastLayoutManagerState` - let me know.