# Restore RecyclerView's scroll position after performing Fragment replace()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-scrollview, android-savedstate

I have a simple activity with two fragment: main (contains a list of items) and detail. Details screen is a fragment, which is displayed when an item is clicked in main list. `DetailFragment` is being shown using [`replace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)).

After navigating back from detail screen I would like to have exact same scroll position in `RecyclerView` that I left it with.

As long as `replace()` initiates `onDestroyView()` and `onCreateView()` cycle to happen for `MainFragment`, after coming back from `DetailFragment` the `RecyclerView` has a scroll position of 0 (at the top), because this is a brand new `RecyclerView` which has no connection to the one that was there before leaving to `DetailFragment`.

`replace()`ing fragment does **not** initiate `onSaveInstanceState()` to be called, that's why using techniques outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerviews-scroll-position-using-recyclerview-state) are not applicable.

I wonder what is the correct way of handling this use-case?

Of course I can save the position on `onDestroyView()` and later manually scroll to that position, but maybe I'm missing some obvious solution?

An answer, that will propose to use [`add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) instead of `replace()` is not welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had `RecyclerView` declared as a child of `NestedScrollView`. This was the issue.

When I got rid of `NestedScrollView` everything was handled automatically.

Answer (score -1):

As `onSaveInstanceState()` is not possible, try using `ViewModel` to save the required data.

When you declare and set the adapter to your first recyclerview, try having a call back to your actvity passing the adapter instance , where in your activity you can try saving the `adapter instance or any required data` in the `ViewModel` of your activity.

Once you come back from your details fragment you can get the saved instance of your reycycler data  from the activity`s ViewModel.

Comment: Why should I save some state of a `Fragment` in the hosting activity? I sure can save scroll position to the `ViewModel` of the fragment, and that can be done in `onDestroyView()`, but my question is how to refrain from this action and make the system save/restore the state automatically. As mentioned in the question, I know about this solution, I'm looking for another solution.