# How to savedInstanceState my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`, data is loaded into it in real time, how do I make `saveInstanceState`? That is, so that when you rotate the screen, it does not go to the beginning of the list, but remains in the same position?

`Fragment` is where the `RecyclerView`

```
public class FragmentPraList extends Fragment {
    CardView cv_pra_list;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Tasks");

    AdapterTasksPraList adapterTasksPraList;
    RecyclerView rv_tasks_pra;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager RLM_tasks_pra;
    static ArrayList<ItemTasks> itemTasks;

    public static FragmentPraList newInstance() {
        return new FragmentPraList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pra_list, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        cv_pra_list = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cv_pra_list);
        cv_pra_list.setOnClickListener(v -> requireActivity().onBackPressed());

        Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("TurnTasksPra", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemTasks> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemTasks>()
                .setQuery(query, ItemTasks.class)
                .build();

        adapterTasksPraList = new AdapterTasksPraList(itemTasks, (ClickTasksBlanc) getContext(), firestoreRecyclerOptions);
        rv_tasks_pra = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rv_pra_list);
        RLM_tasks_pra = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv_tasks_pra.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rv_tasks_pra.setLayoutManager(RLM_tasks_pra);
        rv_tasks_pra.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        rv_tasks_pra.setAdapter(adapterTasksPraList);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapterTasksPraList.startListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't set the adapter over and over again.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I didn't understand your answer, would you describe it?

Comment: Did you try using `layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()` method in conjunction with `layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state)`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43905725/5647037) may help you out. Also, on that question I linked, there's a few other ways to do it (manually save the position of the first visible item, for instance).