# Impelement two recyclerview in one screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I implement this kind of UI, where we have two recyclerViews. One scrolls horizontally and the second one vertically. when the second one scrolls first one also scrolls top together.

[image]

I tried to implement using NestedScrollView, but I had to make second recyclerView height wrap content which causes recyclerView not recycle.

The second way that I tried was having one recyclerView. And adding horizontal recyclerview as a header. The problem was to save header recyclerview scroll state when navigation. And there had been crashes when loading next page (paging 3) in header recyclerView.

The question is: Is there any optimal solution for this kind of ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases, Like this, **you don't have to use 2 `RecyclerView` and you also have to avoid using `RecyclerView` inside`ScrollView`.** instead of this you have to use **one `vertical RecyclerView`** with **multitype** view `Adapter`.
in this way, you are going to have 2 different `ViewHolder` one of them is a horizontal recyclerView (your top item) and the other one is your other items.
for learning multitype adapter you can see this:
[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types)

and for a horizontal recyclerView inside a vertical RecyclerView you can see this :
https://medium.com/@ashishkudale/android-list-inside-list-using-recyclerview-73cff2c4ea95

you have to combine these 2.

[image]

I could not understand the meaning of "header" where you said "adding horizontal recyclerview as a header" but if you did what I told and the problem is the state of inner Horizontal recyclerView, I think probably you are calling `setAdapter` method of horizontal RecyclerView in OnBind() method of your vertical recycler view, it is a common mistake that I have seen in many tutorials.
if you have done this mistake , try to call setAdapter of your inner recyclerView in the constructor of its `viewHolder` and just update the list using `yourHorizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in onBind() method of `VerticalRecylerView`,
and if its not the case and your recyclerView is completely destroying see this link :[How to save RecyclerView's scroll position using RecyclerView.State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerviews-scroll-position-using-recyclerview-state)

Comment: I did the same. But the problem is that: How can I restore scroll position state when navigate to another fragment and navigate back?

Comment: @XudoyshukurJo'rayev I have updated my answer see the end of it.